# gridviewScroll.min.js file not loading first time

Tags: jquery

Am using js file `gridviewScroll.min.js` for gridview,

My issue is first time grid view loading but some alignment issues reflecting

if i sorting,paging that time it comes nice

In below function calling id

```
function gvException() {
        gridviewScroll($('#<%= gvBulkException.ClientID%>'));
    }
```

u can see in attached http://i.stack.im

[image]

Comment: Try to increase height of row in grid.

Comment: Thanks Manoj.
But it's not height issue. when i visit first time js file not loading if i did any post back functions means sorting or paging that time it will aligned automatically